# replacing nested for loop with lapply()

Tags: r, function, for-loop, apply, lapply

I have sen this example to explain how to replace an nested for loop with the lapply() function. However i do not fully understand what is happening in the nested for loop?

according to my understanding, the for loop creates for every country for all years two new variables called `tempX` and `tempY`, but what happens in the last line of the argument in the for loop?

what is the purpose of `variable1` and `variable2` ?

```
# Generate random data:
allCountries <- LETTERS[1:10]
allYears <- 1990:2012

myData <- expand.grid(allCountries, allYears)  # create a dataframe with all possible combinations
colnames(myData) <- c("Country", "Year")
myData$variable1 <- rnorm(nrow(myData))
myData$variable2 <- rnorm(nrow(myData))

# Silly function to perform
myFunction <- function(x, y){
  x * y - x / y
}

### Doubly-nested loop ###
myData$computedFigure <- NA  # Make an "empty" variable in my data.frame

for(ii in allCountries){
  for(jj in allYears){
    tempX <- myData[myData$Country == ii & myData$Year == jj, c("variable1")]
    tempY <- myData[myData$Country == ii & myData$Year == jj, c("variable2")]
    # "Save" results into appropriate location in my data.frame
    myData[myData$Country == ii & myData$Year == jj, c("computedFigure")] <- myFunction(tempX, tempY)
  }
}

### Simple lapply() approach ###
computedFigureList <- lapply(1:nrow(myData), function(x){
  tempX <- myData[x, c("variable1")]
  tempY <- myData[x, c("variable2")]
  # "Save" results into appropriate location in my data.frame
  myFunction(tempX, tempY)
})

myData$computedFigure2 <- unlist(computedFigureList)
with(myData, plot(computedFigure, computedFigure2))
```

Comment: `variable1` and `variable2` are just data. Could be GDP($) and MedianIncome($). Or whatever other variables you might perform math on. They're just made up data.

Comment: The last line in the for loop locates the position in the dataframe where you want to put the results `myData[...,...]` and then puts the results of the math in there `myFunction(tempX,tempY`.

Comment: Instead of using `lapply` with an anonymous function, you could just use 
`myData$computedFigure <- mapply(myFunction, myData$variable1, myData$variable2)`

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of the loop `myData[myData$Country == ii & myData$Year == jj, c("computedFigure")] <- myFunction(tempX, tempY)`
, the function `myFunction`is applied and recorded in the `computedFigure` column.

variable1 and variable2 are set randomly to illustrate the data in myData (x and y) in `myFunction`.

The for loops are exploring the combinations in countries and years...
The two codes (for loop and lappy) will not generate exactly the same result. The lapply will generate a list just with the result of the `myFunction`. The for loops will generate a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need nested `*apply` functions, you can actually use `outer` + `diag` to compute `computedFigure`, which can achieve the same results as you did via nested `for` loop.

```
myData$computedFigure <- diag(with(myData,outer(variable1,variable2,myFunction)))
```